# space of schwartz, problem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

my question is:

Let $f\in S(\mathbb{R})$, with $f(0)=0$, then there exists $g\in S(\mathbb{R})$ such that: 
$$ f(x)=xg(x)\;\text{ for all }\;x\in \mathbb{R}.$$

I need to prove this.

Comment: Check that the function $g(x) := \begin{cases} \dfrac{f(x)}{x}, & x \ne 0, \\ 0, & x = 0 \end{cases}$ is from $S(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: The value in $0$ ought to be $f'(0)$ of course. @njguliyev typo'ed.

Comment: @DanielFischer, as usual... Thanks for correcting.

Comment: I am trying to understand, thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a convenient way to define $g$ which is

> $$
> g(x)=\int_0^1f'(tx)dt\qquad \forall x\in \mathbb{R}
> $$

This handles $x\neq 0$ and $x=0$ simultaneously. Then it only remains to differentiate under the integral, etc...

Comment: The only problem is to prove that we can differentiate under the integral.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy There is a theorem for that.

Comment: Of course; but checking all its conditions - in my opinion - is quite a tedious work, especially for higher order derivatives.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy If the integral was, say, over $\mathbb{R}$, maybe. But it's over $[0,1]$ and  $f$ is smooth. So this really is easy with the integral representation.

Comment: I am trying to understand, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Note that on $\Bbb R\setminus \{0\}$ the function $f(x)/x$ is $\mathcal C^\infty$ and it still satisfies the decreasing properties on infinity. The only thing to prove is that in zero our function $g(x)=f(x)/x$ is still $\mathcal C^\infty$.

First of all, obviously $g(0)=f'(0)$ by L'Hôpital's rule. Then again, you need to show that $$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(f(x)/x)$$is continuous at zero. Leibnitz rule will give us
$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(f(x)/x) = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n-k}(n-k)!\binom{n}{k}\frac{f^{(k)}(x)}{x^{n-k+1}}$$
$$=(-1)^{n}\frac{n!}{x^{n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{f^{(k)}(x)(-x)^{k}}{k!}.$$
The sum - easy to recognise - is a Taylor developement of $f(0)$ in the point $x$, hence we can replace it by $f(0) - (-1)^{n+1}\frac{f^{(n+1)}(x)(-x)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}+\mathcal O(x^{n+2}) $, which results in 
the following:

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(f(x)/x)= \frac{n!}{x^{n+1}} \left(  \frac{f^{(n+1)}(x)(-x)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}+\mathcal O(x^{n+2})\right).$$ It's evident that the limit $x\to 0$ exist and is equal to $\frac{ f^{(n+1)}(0)}{n+1}$, which concludes the proof.

Comment: I investigate the taylor expansion can not be applied if there are points of singularity in the domain of the function

Comment: @Wmmoreno The term $\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{f^{(k)}(x)(-x)^{k}}{k!}$ is a Taylor expansion of $f$, which is $\mathcal C^\infty(\Bbb R)$, so no problems with singularities there.

Comment: I am trying to understand, thanks